# Why do the old and new APK diffs not add up?

Tags: android, apk, proguard, android-r8

I'm trying to reduce the size of an APK and I made the R8 minimization more aggressive by

- Using the `proguard-android-optimize.txt` file instead of the regular
- Removing the contents of local `proguard-rules.pro` file to reduce exceptions

The build succeeded and I analyzed the APK using Android Studio's tool. I have attached a screenshot of the output. I don't understand why the old and new size only differ by 0.2 MB when the sum of the "Diff Size" column is around -2.2 MB.

Could somebody please help me understand the image?

[image]

Comment: The apk is compressed.  Those size differences are uncompressed most likely.

Comment: Depending on the version of Android Studio the APK analyzer can give misleading numbers, as shared debug information can be counted multiple times (for each method sharing the info). The uncompressed size of the DEX files is what you shold look at.